GitHub Branch Ruleset - how to specify what items require a pull request
I have a repo that has .github, src directories and a README.md file.
I would like to be able to make changes to whatever is in .github folder or to the README.md file without the need for the pull request. However the pull request should be required on any changes in the src folder. I cannot find the settings in the Branch Ruleset that would allow that.
An example of that would be working on the actions that are in the .github folder and creating a pull request each time is not needed and annoying.
If this were a part of a GitHub Action, it would have something like this:
on:
  workflow_dispatch: 
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
      - dev 
    paths:
      - 'src/**'

how do I do something like this for a Ruleset?
in other workds, how do I make ruleset apply to the src directory of the repo and not to the whole repo?
Or do I need a different approach for that?



I'm using so many different branches:

master(protected)
dev
test
prod
hotfix
bugfix
refactor or cleanup
feature/{name of the branch}

I think the pipeline is only triggered when pushing or merging the features with the master branch. I'm using the dev branch when I'm gonna work on the dev environment. I'm using this Template.
I update this template for your question.
name: CI

# the placeholder `$default-branch` will be automatically replaced with
# the name of the repository's default branch, e.g. main
on:
  push:
    branches: [$default-branch]
  pull_request:
    branches: [$default-branch]

jobs:
  enforce-pr:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Check for changes in src directory
        id: check_changes
        run: |
          git fetch origin main
          CHANGED_FILES=$(git diff --name-only HEAD origin/main)
          echo "Changed files: $CHANGED_FILES"
          if echo "$CHANGED_FILES" | grep -q '^src/'; then
            echo "::set-output name=changes_in_src::true"
          else
            echo "::set-output name=changes_in_src::false"
          fi

      - name: Fail if changes in src directory
        if: steps.check_changes.outputs.changes_in_src == 'true'
        run: |
          echo "Changes detected in src directory. Please create a pull request."
          exit 1


My question was about a ruleset for a branch and that I need it to require a pull request before merge only if the changes were made in the SRC folder, but it would allow direct push if I made a change to readme.md or actions in .guthub folder.
